# How to hide/show video in Cordova Opentok plugin for video call in Ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, opentok

I am using this Opentok plugin for video calling features in an Ionic application. I have to hide/show video based on the certain condition in the single screen but I am not able to find any help from given plugin link.

https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok

Try to hide video using CSS class

```
.OT_root video {
   display: none !important;
}
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here (I also help maintain the [Cordova OpenTok plugin](https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok)).

The Cordova OpenTok plugin uses the native OpenTok SDKs and places native iOS and Android views for the [Publisher](https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok/blob/master/docs/publisher.md) and [Subscriber](https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok/blob/master/docs/subscriber.md) on top of a WebView div element. This means that the native views are superimposed on the div elements that are created in the DOM.

After you apply the CSS changes, you have to call [`OT.updateViews`](https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok/tree/master/docs#important-notes) to relay this information to the native layer indicating that the view was changed. The `updateViews` method sends the DOM position, width, height, and etc over the JS bridge to the native layer which then uses that information to update the native view appropriately.

You can do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('publisher').style = 'display: none !important;';
OT.updateViews();
```

Note that in the code above, we are assuming that the `publisher` div element has the Id set to  `publisher`. You can change the code to however you've set up your code.

Please note that hiding the view will simply hide it from the screen, but will not stop publishing of the video. To stop publishing, use either `session.unpublish(publisher)` or `publisher.destroy`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. CSS written in question that is correct? I have call updateViews after that you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I've updated my answer to reflect the changes

Comment: Tried same but not working. Can you please look here what I am dong. http://keepnote.cc/opentok

Comment: I just ran your code and it looks like it's does not work when you set div.style.display = 'none !important;' - please instead use the code sample above.
I've also gone ahead and updated the keepnote for a sample with your code.

Comment: Getting error Cannot assign to 'style' because it is a read-only property.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure - this seems like an Ionic things. I'm able to assign a value to the `style` property. Could you please share a sample app on GH that I can run and test out?

Comment: Mr Manik, I found that not all css is working (ex. border, border-radius, z-index..) , so what css can we use other than height and width? I am trying to use z-index since when the other person inter the call after me, the publisher div will hide behind the subscriber..

Comment: Hey Rami - some of the things such as z-Index are not supported by the Cordova plugin. I recommend you filing an issue on the plugin repo as you discover things :)

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking at ways to achieve what OP asks for, this is how I managed to make it.

I tried doing as Manik explained but it seems that `display: none !important;` is not very reliable, so I decided to move the videos that should not display offscreen.

Example (hide) with a subscriber which has the element id 'subscriber':

```
document.getElementById('subscriber').style = 'top: 5000px!important; position: fixed!important;';
OT.updateViews();
```

I guess you could also use `left` instead of `top`.

Bear in mind that this does not interrupt the video stream, it just hides the publisher/subscriber (see Manik's explanation).